# Adding Number to Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add and delete the number "7" based on a user checking a checkbox and then display that number on the page:

```
var theTotal = 0;

 $("#highlightChk").change(function() {
      var ishchecked= $(this).is(':checked');
      if(!ishchecked)  theTotal -= 7;
      if(ishchecked) theTotal += 7;

}); 

$('#total').text(theTotal);
```

When I display the code it is "0" even when I check the checkbox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$('#total').text(theTotal);` You need to put this in that change callback. Otherwise you just give `#total` the init value, but dosen't give it a new value to display when `theTotal` is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place an initial value in `#total` and each time an operation is being done read the value and parse it and add to or subtract from it. The `#total` element has to be updated within the `change` event handler.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#highlightChk").on('change', function() {
        //READ & PARSE existing value
        var total = +$('#total').text();
        //INC-/DECREMENT value accordingly
        total += this.checked ? 7 : -7;
        //UPDATE DOM with new value
        $('#total').text( total ); //<<--- BELONGS INSIDE
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="highlight" id="highlightChk"/> Highlight<br><br>
Total: <div id="total">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `$('#total').text(theTotal);` inside the change method

```
$("#highlightChk").change(function () {
    var theTotal = 0;
    var ishchecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    if (!ishchecked) theTotal -= 7;
    else theTotal += 7;
    $('#total').text(theTotal);
});
```

Since `theTotal` as a global variable is always `0`, but when it's inside the local scope of the jquery `.change()` method you will always get the correct changed value.

[**`FIDDLE DEMO #1`**](http://jsfiddle.net/wy5ny2hn/)

You can also achieve the same result with less code like:-

```
$("#highlightChk").change(function () {
    $('#total').text(this.checked ? 7 : 0);
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO #2`**](http://jsfiddle.net/wy5ny2hn/1/)

Comment: perhaps explaining a bit more would be better :)